# Is it possible to use Caffe Only for classification without any training?

Tags: machine-learning, nvidia, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Some users might see this as opinion-based-question but if you look closely, I am trying to explore use of Caffe as a purely testing platform as opposed to currently popular use as training platform.

**Background:**

1. I have installed all dependencies using Jetpack 2.0 on Nvidia TK1.
2. I have installed caffe and its dependencies successfully.
3. The MNIST example is working fine.

**Task:**

1. I have been given a convnet with all standard layers. (Not an opensource model)
2. The network weights and bias values etc are available *after training*. The training has not been done via caffe. (Pretrained Network)
3. The weights and bias are all in the form of MATLAB matrices. (Actually in a .txt file but I can easily write code to get them to be matrices)
4. I CANNOT do training of this network with caffe and must used the given weights and bias values ONLY for classification.
5. I have my own dataset in the form of 32x32 pixel images.

**Issue:**
In all tutorials, details are given on how to deploy and train a network, and then use the generated .proto and .caffemodel files to validate and classify. Is it possible to implement this network on caffe and directly use my weights/bias and training set to classify images? What are the available options here? I am a caffe-virgin so be kind. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue here is:
*How to initialize caffe net from text file weights*?

I assume you have a `'deploy.prototxt'` describing the net's architecture (layer types, connectivity, filter sizes etc.). The only issue remaining is how to set the internal weights of `caffe.Net` to pre-defined values saved as text files.

You can get access to `caffe.Net` internals, see [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) tutorial on how this can be done in python.

Once you are able to set the weights according to your text file, you can `net.save(...)` the new weights into a binary `caffemodel` file to be used from now on. You do not have to train the net if you already have trained weights, and you can use it for generating predictions ("test").